# perl array unique values

Tags: arrays, perl, unique

I am trying to write code that confirms every row in 2 dimensional array has all unique values.

`@x2 = uniq( @q2 );` produced array with 10 elements instead of 6; then `$y2 = @x2;` produced 1??

I don't understand why x2 is different than x1 and y2 is different than y1? I am expecting x2 with 5 elements and y2=5 (just like y1). How can I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @q1 = (6,0,0,5,0,7,0,0,1,0);
my @x1 = uniq( @q1 );
my $y1 = @x1;
print "y1 = ",Dumper( $y1 );
print "x1 = ",Dumper( @x1 );
print "q1 = ",Dumper( @q1 );

print '====='."\n";

my @b = ();
push @{ $b[0] }, (0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7);
push @{ $b[1] }, (6,0,0,5,0,7,0,0,1,0);

my $r=1;
my @q2=$b[$r];
my @x2 = uniq( @q2 );
my $y2 = @x2;
print "y2 = ",Dumper( $y2 );
print "x2 = ",Dumper( @x2 );
print "q2 = ",Dumper( @q2 );
print "b[r]=",Dumper( $b[$r] );
```

Comment: my @q2= @{ $b[$r]} ;   this

Comment: That `@q2` in the shown code doesn't have 10 elements (?) -- you assign `$b[1]` to it, an array reference so a single scalar.  So `@x2` has the same, one element which is an array reference.  Do as @Сухой27 says instead, `@{$b[$r]}`.

Comment: Tip: There's no point in assigning zero scalars (`= ()`) to a newly-created array (`my @b`). It's already empty.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays can only contains scalars. This means they can't contain arrays, at least not directly. So we use references to arrays as array elements (since references are scalars).

Thanks to autovivification,

```perl
push @{ $b[0] }, (0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7);
```

is short for

```perl
push @{ $b[0] //= [] }, (0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7);
```

And `[]` returns a *reference* to a newly created array.

So when you do `my @q2 = $b[$r];`, you are assigning a single scalar to `@q2` (the one created by the implicit `[]`). To copy the elements of the array referenced by `$b[$r]`, you can use

```
my @q2 = @{ $b[$r] };
```

---

As an aside, the following can be written better:

```perl
push @{ $b[0] }, (0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7);
```

Since `$b[0]` doesn't exist when this is executed, we can use

```perl
$b[0] = [0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7];
```

Finally, there's no reason to hardcode `0`. We could use

```perl
push @b, [0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7];
```

So we get

```perl
my @b;  # Note the lack of a useless, noisy "= ()".
push @b, [0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7];
push @b, [6,0,0,5,0,7,0,0,1,0];
```

or

```perl
my @b = (
   [0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7],
   [6,0,0,5,0,7,0,0,1,0],
);
```